# tooltip java setToolTipText con focus gained o key typed java

Tags: java, tooltip

Estoy precisando hacer visible un tooltip en un JTextField en java. La idea es que cuando el focus se concentre en el textfield o bien cuando comiencen a escribir. Se haga visible la ayuda del utilizando el setToolTipText.
No he logrado hacer esto, pero tengo el siguiente código que al pasar el mouse sobre el JTextField logra mostrar la ayuda pero no cuando escribo.

```
    private void buscadorTextFieldKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                             
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent.TYPED) {
        buscadorTextField.setToolTipText("Presione ENTER para realizar la busqueda");
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He añadido el mensaje del tooltip directamente al componente `TextField` (en mi caso la variable se llama `textNombre`):

```java
textNombre.setToolTipText("Presione ENTER para realizar la busqueda");
```

Luego, he añadido un listener al mismo componente para el evento ´KeyPress´:

```java
 private void textNombreKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
        final ToolTipManager manager = ToolTipManager.sharedInstance();
        final int oldDelay = manager.getInitialDelay();
        manager.setInitialDelay(0);
        manager.mouseMoved(new MouseEvent(textNombre, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0,
                0, false));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            manager.setInitialDelay(oldDelay);
        });
    }
```

El código del listener está tomado de [esta respuesta de StackOverflow Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39803911/18473608) (nota que existen más respuestas y puedes probarlas todas).

El resultado final se muestra en esta animación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @nonameyet, muchas gracias por la ayuda, me re sirvió el código que me compartiste. Me costo entender al principio pero nada, despues reemplace el textNombre por el nombre del textField, y importe el java.awt.event.MouseEvent y funciono perfecto. MUCHAS PERO MUCHAS GRACIAS.